# Include imported content in sitecore search result item

Tags: content-search, lucene

We are on Sitecore 8.1 using Lucene search index. I have an item with  presentation details and displays properly on the site. The item has several child items pulled from a separate folder in the tree and puts them in an accordion on the item when displayed.

Problem is that if you try to search for content that is included in the child items they are not part of the result of the specified item.

I understand why but trying to see if there is a way to get the accordion data to show in the search result for the specified item.

Can someone point me in the right direction if possible?

Comment: Assuming the related templates are not excluded in Lucene Index Configuration. Can you please add more details helpful to understand your problem more precisely?